# How to get last generated error in MySQL from DB Adapter

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework2

I'm pulling the hair on this one.

In ZF1 it was easy as it would raise an exception with full sql error details. In ZF2 it only raises Exception\RuntimeException which only passes the description of error and not the number which makes it impossible to work with.

Question: how to get the full error out of the Adapter. Here is the snippet of the code I use:

```
$dbAdapter = $this->_serviceManaget->get('Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter');

try {
    $result = $dbAdapter->query($sql, $binds);
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    //here I need to check the error number raised by MySQL during the execution
    //$e object in this case only contains 
    //$e->message = "Duplicate entry 'blablabla' for key 319" and $e->code = 0   
}
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In ZF2 Exceptions extended from PHP [**SPL Exceptions**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/spl.exceptions.php). They all extends standard Exception interface. Following [**Exception** manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.exception.php) you can do this:

```
try {
    $result = $dbAdapter->query($sql, $binds);
} catch (\Exception $e) {        
    $code = $e->getCode();
    $msg  = $e->getMessage();
    $file = $e->getFile();
    $line = $e->getLine();
    echo "$file:$line ERRNO:$code ERROR:$msg";       
}
```

FYI you can implement multiple catches for different exception types like this:

```
try {
    ...
} catch (\RuntimeException $e) {
    ...
} catch (\LogicException $e) {
    ...
}
```

**Update:**
For getting error data directly from `\mysqli` instance:

```
try {
    $result = $dbAdapter->query($sql, $binds);
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    $mysqli = $dbAdapter->getDriver()->getConnection()->getResource();        
    $file = $e->getFile();
    $line = $e->getLine();
    echo "$file:$line ERRNO:$mysqli->errno ERROR:$mysqli->error";       
}
```

For more information about how to obtain `\mysqli` errors and warnings data check [**manual**](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but please read the description and the code more carefully. It sais that code = "0" and message = "Duplicate entry 'blablabla' for key 319". So, to rephrase, I need to somehow get the MySQLi object out of Adapter in order to pull the "last DB generated error" out of it.